# Common Modulus Attack not reproducible

Tags: rsa

I want to calculate a simple example of the RSA common modulus attack. However, the result is not correct and I do not find my mistake.

p=$29,
q=37,
n=p*q = 1073,
\phi(n) = 1008,
e1 = 5,
e2 = 11$

Let $m = 999$.

$c_1 = m^{e_1} \pmod n = 296$, 
$c_2 = m^{e_2} \pmod n = 555$

The extended Euclidean algorithm gives me $y_1$ and $y_2$: $y_1 \cdot e_1 + y_2 \cdot e_2 = 1$

$y_1 = -2, y_2 = 1$ (edited)

$m = c_1^{y_1} * c_2^{y_2} = 296^{-2} \cdot 555^1 \pmod {1073}$

How do I calculate $296^{-2}$? I tried to get the inverse of $296 \pmod {1073}$ and then square it, but $296$ has no inverse. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not noticing that m is not coprime to n. ​ (Encryption followed by decryption still gives the original input, but such an m [that's also not a multiple of n] gives a non-trivial factorization of n, and the ciphertext will have the same property.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The original RSA encryption scheme does not require m to be coprime to n. Why is this necessary when conducting the common modulus attack?

Comment: I haven't checked this, but think it's not actually necessary. ​ One could instead try using [meadow inverses](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352220814000546). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: But as we see that the attack above does not work, because "m is not coprime to n". So it seems to be a prerequisite, doesn't it?

Comment: I just checked, it _does_ work. ​ The meadow inverse of 296 is 962. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Dememer: yes; you reduced the problem to finding an efficient way to compute the meadow inverse of a given $c$ modulo $n$ of unknown factorization when $c$ has no regular inverse, and is not $0$.

Comment: @fgrieu : ​ Yes, and that can be done with gcd and [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Actually I still have no response to my question. I do not know how to calculate 296^-2. I cannot reconstruct m = 999.

Answer (score 2):

In real word RSA modules are so large that probability for finding $c_1$ which is not coprime with $n$ is approximately zero.

> Also if you founded such number then $p=gcd(c_1,n)\neq1$ so $p$ is a factor of $n$ and in this case attack is not necessary because $n$ is factored.

$gcd(296,1073)=37\neq 1$ so $p=37,q=\frac{1073}{37}=29$ and $\phi(n)=1008$

Now you can easily compute private key $d_2$:

$e_2\cdot d_2=1 \pmod{ \phi(n)}$ so $d_2=275$.

> $$m={c_2}^{d2}\pmod n={555}^{275}\pmod{1073}=999$$

Comment: How does your answer help me in solving the upper exercise?

Comment: @null, The goal of attack is breaking RSA. With factoring $n$ you can easily find private key and decrypt ciphertext. If your question is compute $d$ which $296\cdot d\pmod{1073}=1$ you cant find such $d$.

Comment: I understand. Well if I cannot invert d the upper attack is not possible. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to reliably and efficiently find message $m$ (with $0\le m<n$) given RSA modulus $n$, distinct RSA public exponents $e_1$ and $e_2$ coprime to each others and to the unknown $\phi(n)$, and ciphertexts $c_1=m^{e_1}\bmod n$ and $c_2=m^{e_2}\bmod n$. WLoG, and per the corrected question, $y_1$ is negative when it is applied the [extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to $e_1$ and $e_2$ in order to find $y_1$ and $y_2$ with $y_1\cdot e_1+y_2\cdot e_2=1$.

For random choice of message $m$, odds that $\gcd(m,n)=0$ are low, precisely $1-\phi(n)/n$, that is $1/p+1/q-1/n$ if $n=p\cdot q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes. If $n$ is [square-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) (as assumed in most definitions of RSA), $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m^e_1,n)$, thus odds that $\gcd(c_1,n)=0$ also are $1-\phi(n)/n$. Hence, odds that $c_1$ has no inverse for random choice of $m$ are low (less than $2^{-510}$ of 1024-bit RSA with two 512-bit primes factors). Hence, for overwhelmingly most $m$, $c_1^{y_1}\cdot c_2^{y_2}\bmod n$ is well-defined, and is the desired $m$. But that does not quite always work.

We can make an efficient algorithm that always work, including for the definition of RSA in [PKCS#1v2](http://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf) where $n$ can have multiple prime factors, even though we might be unable to efficiently find any prime factor in $n$. The method goes:

- Check if $c_1=0$, in which case $m=0$.
- Compute $r=\gcd(c_1,n)$. That's a divisor of $n$, often $1$ (however it is possible that $r>1$, in which case $r$ divides $n$; and also that $r$ or/and $n/r$ are composite, thus factoring $n$ might remain uneasy).
- Compute $s=n/r$; with the assumption that $n$ is square-free, $\gcd(r,s)=1$ holds.
- Compute $i_1=((((c_1\bmod s)\cdot r)\bmod s)^{-1}\bmod s)\cdot r$, the so-called [meadow inverse](http://meadowsite.wordpress.com/) of $c_1$ modulo $n$, such that $i_1\cdot c_1\bmod r=0$ and $i_1\cdot c_1\bmod s=1$, with $r$ and $s$ defined as above.
- Compute $i_1^{-y_1}\cdot c_2^{y_2}\bmod n$, which is the desired $m$ (as pointed by Ricky Demer in a [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/32506/5#comment75766_3250655) to the question).

Proof sketch: we prove $i_1^{-y_1}\cdot c_2^{y_2}-m\equiv0\pmod r$ and  $i_1^{-y_1}\cdot c_2^{y_2}-m\equiv0\pmod s$.

Example: $e_1=5$, $e_2=11$, $n=837876170870196973028071$, $c_1=621961884462245272210948$, $c_2=653042419105836777869045$. We compute

- $r=932340427217$; that's a factor of $n$ (this example is crafted to make it composite)
- $s=898680510263$; that's a factor of $n$ (also composite in this example)
- $i_1=653042419105836777869045$
- $m=331563319321409011786785$.

Note: we do not need to factor $n$ (or $r$ or $s$), as required to compute a valid private exponent $d$, as would be required by the method outlined in that [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32514/555); and we always find $m$ with polynomial effort w.r.t. the bit size of parameters, contrary to the method in that [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32528/555).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually "invert" a value m with respect to n even if

$$gcd(m,n) \neq 1$$

You are looking for a value $m^{-1}$ that satisfies

$$m*m^{-1} = 1 \pmod{n}$$

This is a [linear congruence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearCongruenceEquation.html). You need a bit more time to solve than just simply inverting a number. But by trying all the possible values as specified in the link above, you will finally discover the "inverse" you are looking for.

Comment: Um, no you can't. By definition, if $\gcd(m,n) = k$, then *any* multiple of $m$ modulo $n$ is also a multiple of $k$. The closest you can get is finding a pseudoinverse $m^*$ such that $m \times m^* = k \pmod n$ (and you can do that with the same extended Euclidean algorithm used to find normal modular inverses).

Comment: Yes, and if you try every possible pseudoinverse as you call it, one of them will be the message and it will allow you to perform the common modulus attack.